# Capturing set_time_limit() reached - PHP

Tags: php, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to catch the fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861033/how-to-catch-the-fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-in-p)

I have used `set_time_limit(60);` many times before. But is there anyway of capturing when this is exceeded, at the moment it just bombs with the same old error.

I want to capture it failing and then handle it in my own way?

Comment: I fear the limit is the limit, I'm not aware there is a softlimit you could catch. I'd say you should do some more research and come back to outline what you've found out. E.g. is that a catchable fatal error even?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From comment section in php.net for [set_time_limit](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php#92949)

```
<?php
set_time_limit(60);
ob_start();
function shutdown () {
  $out = ob_get_clean();echo $out; // echo output if required
  // do your processing code
}
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

// your code
?>
```

Comment: Hmm. I didn't think that would work, but [the code here](http://codepad.org/vCJklBng) actually works on my server (although not on codepad, which may have it's own custom timeout handler).

Comment: Here is the demo code on my site, with a one second timeout: http://jfcoder.com/t/timeout.php And the code-behind: http://pastebin.com/FwBBA0qy

Comment: @JaredFarrish yes, it works on my server too. `codepad` would be having some mechanism to block long loops and handle timeouts.