# PHP - Stop The execution after a finite time

Tags: php

Is there any way we can perform an action if the php script execution time exceeds a certain time?

I could see there is set_time_limit function which throws a fatal error after a certain time. But I am not able to catch this fatal error and perform an action in this case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: add you own timmer, and check it

Comment: duplication.. and there is an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650961/capturing-set-time-limit-reached-php

Comment: `set_time_limit(30);` put seconds

Answer (score 7):

Could be wrong but I thnk the suggested dupe would end the script, while it sounds like you want to continue the script but end that loop part of it after x seconds.

If so before you start your loop set the time -

```
$starttime = time();
```

then within your loop add an -

```
$now = time()-$starttime;
if ($now > 30) {             //assuming you're looking at 30 seconds
break;
}
```

then end your loop. After 30 seconds the loop will stop and the script will progress.