# How do I handle Fatal Error in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting a huge data values through CSV file via HTML form.

I have used `set_time_limit(0);` so that script run until the whole operation is not performed.

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\clytics\include\clytics.database.php on line 135

Now, I am trying to catch this fatal error.

Comment: @JeremyMiller The answer there says to use `set_time_limit(0)`, and that's what he's done.

Comment: actually, I want to use try, catch to handle this error.
Is it possible...

Comment: You can't try-catch this error.  It's not something that happens within any given block of code, it occurs outside of all that.  And, good point Barmar.

Comment: For the try-catch consideration, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861033/how-to-catch-the-fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-in-p

Comment: Use cli for this.. You can check `exec` in php for this

Answer (score 2):

> I have used set_time_limit(0); so that script run until the whole
>   operation is not performed.

Probably needs more memory as well. Basically your code is just a hog & you need to tame the way it is gobbling up resources.

But that is just a tangent on the overall architecture issues you might be facing.

Specific to there issue, is there something in your code that would override that value of `set_time_limit(0);`?

Also, ar you running this script via the command line or the PHP in Apache? Because the CLI config `php.ini` is 100% different form the Apache module config of `php.ini`.

For example, on Ubuntu the Apache PHP `php.ini` is here:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

But the command line (CLI) `php.ini` is here:

```
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

And if you want to brute force your script to eat up memory regardless of your config settings, you can add this to the top of your PHP file:

```
ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1);
```

If one reads up more on [`set_time_limit`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) this comes up:

> Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is
>   reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30
>   seconds or, if it exists, the max_execution_time value defined in the
>   php.ini.

Then reading up on [`max_execution_time`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) this comes up:

> This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run
>   before it is terminated by the parser. This helps prevent poorly
>   written scripts from tying up the server. The default setting is 30.
>   When running PHP from the command line the default setting is 0.

But then, the magic `300` number shows up:

> Your web server can have other timeout configurations that may also
>   interrupt PHP execution. Apache has a Timeout directive and IIS has a
>   CGI timeout function. **Both default to 300 seconds.** See your web server
>   documentation for specific details.

So now you know where the 300 comes from. But doing `ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1);` should let you run the script without a timeout.

And final bit of info if none of that somehow works: Look into [`max_input_time`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time):

> This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to parse
>   input data, like POST and GET. Timing begins at the moment PHP is
>   invoked at the server and ends when execution begins.

While `max_input_time` might not seem to be related, in some versions of PHP, there is a bug where `max_input_time` and `max_execution_time` are directly connected.

Comment: Memory hog or no, the program is still spewing a time limit error, not an out-of-memory error

Comment: `set_time_limit(0)` is something you do in code, so there's no reason to restart a server.