# PHP timeout error handling

Tags: php, error-handling, timeout

I'm triyng to catch timeout error to output some clear text to the user (like "Sorry, timeout").
So why does this example:

```
function shutdown() { 
    $a=error_get_last(); 
    if($a==null)   
        echo "No errors"; 
    else 
         print_r($a); 

} 
register_shutdown_function('shutdown'); 
ini_set('max_execution_time',1 ); 
sleep(3);
```

output `no errors`?? I'm confused about it.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861033/how-to-catch-the-fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-in-p) this example looks helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try not using sleep(), seems to work if the reason for timeout is real work:

Example

```
function isPrime($num) {
    if($num == 1)
        return false;
    if($num == 2)
        return true;
    if($num % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for($i = 3; $i <= ceil(sqrt($num)); $i = $i + 2) {
        if($num % $i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function shutdown() 
{ 
     $a=error_get_last(); 
     if($a==null)   
         echo "No errors"; 
     else 
          print_r($a); 
} 
register_shutdown_function('shutdown'); 
ini_set('max_execution_time',1 ); 
$ps = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
    if (isPrime($i)){
        $ps++;
    }
}
echo $ps;
```

Comment: Looks useful for me. Thanks!