# Max execution time try catch

Tags: php

Everything is in the title, thus after several search I saw that one to pouver to wrestle this error by the php. Thus I look for a solution for not not that my site shows a blank page (I hide the errors), but rather a page with an error: " impossible to realize your request ". However impossible, I thought of making it with ErrorDocument ( htaccess ),  but it does not work (in localhost). To make?

Sorry for my English

Comment: No worries on the English.  I actually kinda like it... might be trochee.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to catch the fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861033/how-to-catch-the-fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-in-p)

Comment: can you provide us a small example or tell us the scenario in which it occurs. e.g it happens when i try to load xyz etc and so on

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is make use of the `register_shutdown_function()` which will let you do something just before PHP exits.

So in the example below I'm catching errors and checking to see if the message starts with **Maximum execution time of**

> example code

```
set_time_limit(1);

register_shutdown_function(function() {
    $error = error_get_last();

    if ($error['type'] === E_ERROR && strpos($error['message'], 'Maximum execution time of') === 0) {
        echo 'time limit exceeded';
    }
});

for(;;) {}
```

Comment: There must be also isset($error['type']) check, because the $error can be null when the handler invoked on exit() etc

Answer (score 0):

You can add error documents to .htaccess. For timeouts, you need to add one for status code 504. Add the following line to .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 504 /504.html
```

`/504.html` is the relative url to an error page that you want to show. This may be a PHP file as well.

[more information and list of error codes](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-status-code-headers-errordocument.html)