# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded. How to handle this error?

Tags: php, fatal-error

I am getting this error while running one script.

I know it's about execution time and i had went through all answers too but i want to display custom message when this error occurs so that site doesn't break.

How to handle that error as i have kept error display off on my live site so footer is not loaded due to this error which stops breaking my site?

```
http://whois.icann.org/en/lookup?name=google.com
```

When you visit this site its displaying custom error message

Comment: why not fix the script

Comment: @dagon what you mean by fixing script?

Comment: 30 secounds is a crazy amount of time for moist scripts

Comment: ok @Dagon i got what you want to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either increase the maximum execution time by using set_time_limit() or by setting max_execution_time in the php.ini.
Also by setting set_time_limit to 0 you can remove the limit for exceution time.

And if you are using linux you can try with the function register_shutdown_function.This function will be called when the execution time limit is reached.

Comment: have you checked the site i mentioned?

Comment: @Aishwarya Taneja : Ys I checked and updated my answer also .Please check

Answer (score 0):

you can exceed max execution time like this  :

> `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` //300 seconds = 5 minutes

Comment: I mentioned in question i know how to increase max_execution_time.

I don't want to do so, instead i want to display custom message when its max_execution_time error is there.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#106061.this might help

Answer (score 0):

You can always modify your php.ini file. There is a setting for maximum execution time.

Another way is to use `ini_set` function.

Another way is to put the max execution time in your htaccess file.

**EDIT:**

```
The max execution time is not an error and therefore not catchable.

Please check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861033/how-to-catch-the-fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-in-p
```

Finally, there is always scope of fixing the scripts and putting lengthy processes into a queue.

Comment: Finally, there is always scope of fixing the scripts and putting lengthy processes into a queue...

means?

how it can be helpful?

Comment: You can always put long processes in queue like: third party access, video converter logic, emails firing etc everything in background. In queue server. So that your PHP execution can get finished quickly and you can then show a message to user to notify that some processes are still running on background.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this line of code in the file first:

```
set_time_limit(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

change below configuration in `php.ini`

```
max_execution_time = 600; 
max_input_time = 120; 
max_input_nesting_level = 64;
memory_limit = 128M;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '10000');
```

at the first line of your php code