# set_time_limit() Timeout at file level PHP

Tags: php, timeout

```
<?php
echo '<html><body>';
set_time_limit(1);
$i = 0;
while(++$i < 100000001){
        if($i % 100000 == 0){
                echo $i / 100000, "<br/>\n";
        }
}
echo "done.<br/>\n";

// will not echo 'done.'.
?>
```

The above code keeps echoing `echo $i / 100000, "<br/>\n";` till 1 second and then stops the execution since I have used `set_time_limit(1);`

But I want it to echo only if the complete loop gets executed within 1 sec and else instead of echoing I want to pop up or display a message that says `timeout or cannot perform execution in 1 sec`.

Is it possible to achieve this somehow in PHP?

Comment: I hope you want this: [Tracking the script execution time in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535020/tracking-the-script-execution-time-in-php)

Comment: Its a sample code. In a real code, the situation is similar to this. @nice_dev

Comment: You could try and catch the fatal error that occurs when the max execution time is reached, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11704803/1427878

Answer (score 0):

set_time_limit(1) is unsuitable for this task. Just check the runtime of the script with [microtime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php).

```
$stop = microtime(true) + 1;
$i = 0;
while(microtime(true) < $stop){
        if(++$i % 1000000 == 0){
                echo $i / 1000000, "<br/>\n";
        }
}
echo "done.<br/>\n";
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
done.
```

[Test on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/349IK)